# perl: new cpan module maker? local configuration text files and executables, too?

Tags: perl, cpan

I am writing a perl program that I want to share with others, eventually via cpan.  it's getting to the point where I should start thinking about this on a bigger scale.

- a decade ago, I used the h2xs package maker once.  is this still the most recommended way to get started?  there used to be a couple of alternatives.  because I am starting from scratch with very little recollection, anything simple will do at this point.
- I need to read a few long text files (not perl modules) for configuration.  where do I put them and how do I access them, no matter where the module is installed?  (FindBin?)  *_DATA*_ is inconvenient.
- I need to provide an executable (linux and osx).  can putting an executable into the user's path be part of the module installation?  (how?)
- I would like to be able to continue developing it, run it for test purposes, have a new version, repack it, and reupload it easily.
- before uploading to cpan, can I share a cpan bundle for easy local installation to downloaders and testers?

  # cpan < mybundle.cpanbundle

advice appreciated.

regards,

/iaw

Answer (score 6):

If anything I say conflicts with Andy Lester, listen to him instead. He knows more than I ever will.

- [Module::Starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aStarter) is a good, simple way to generate module scaffolding. My take is it's been the default for this sort of thing for a few years now.
- For configuration/support files, I think you probably want [File::ShareDir](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aShareDir). Might be worth considering [Data::Section](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aSection) if it's just a matter of needing multiple `__DATA__` sections though.
- You can certainly [put scripts in the `bin` subdirectory of your distribution](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aAPI#script_files), the build tool will put it in the right place at install time.
- A build tool will take care of the work-flow you describe.
- Bundles are something different. You make a distribution and share the tarball/archive.

If you set up `PERL5LIB` appropriately, then repeat `make test`, `make install`, `make dist` to your heart's content. For development/sharing purposes a lot of projects do their work on github or similar - makes it easy to share. They have private accounts for business purposes too. Very useful if you want to rewind and see where/when a problem was introduced.

If you get a copy of [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm) (simple to install, fairly lightweight) then it can install from a tar.gz file or even direct from a git repository. You can also tell it to install to a local dir ([local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local%3a%3alib) compatible - another utility that's very useful).

Hopefully that's reasonably up-to-date as of 2014. You may see [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist%3a%3aZilla) mentioned for module development. My understanding is that it's most useful for those with a large family of CPAN distributions to manage. Oh - if you (or other readers) aren't aware of them, do check out [autodie](https://metacpan.org/pod/autodie) and [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try%3a%3aTiny) around errors and exceptions, [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) (for a full-featured object-oriented framework) and [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) (for a smaller lightweight version).

I think that advice is all reasonably non-controversial. I find `cpanm` to be much more pleasant than the "full" cpan client, and `Moo` seems pretty popular nowadays too.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, Richard, but I haven't played in the Module::Starter/dzil arena for years.  There's undoubtedly much that I haven't kept up with.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Module::Starter and its much more capable (and complex) successor Dist::Zilla.

Whatever you do, don't use h2xs.  Module::Starter was created specifically because h2xs was such an inappropriate tool for creating distributions.

Comment: is there a tutorial?  the main Module::Starter just tells me that it relies on plugins...

Comment: After you install the module you get a `module-starter` command-line tool.  Basically you just run `module-starter` and it will show you all the options, things like --author and --module and so on.  Basically all you need is `module-starter --module=My::Module::Name --author='Your Name' --email='Your@email.com'` and maybe some others.  Then you'll have a My-Module directory tree created for you with files in it.  I created Module::Starter years ago, but I haven't been the maintainer in a long time and SawyerX has added a ton to it.  But those should be the basics.